# Scala: ordering an Array of column maps

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following array:

```
[{"Date":"2019-01-01","Order id":"1"}, {"Date":"2019-02-01","Order id":"10"}]
```

I want to order it by Date (desc):

```
[{"Date":"2019-02-01","Order id":"10"}, {"Date":"2019-01-01","Order id":"1"}]
```

I was attempting to perform

```
.sortBy(x => (x.$"Date"))
```

But it was clearly wrong:

```
 error: identifier expected but string literal found.
```

Thanks

EDIT

The array is created as a new column of a dataframe

```
df2
  .groupBy(groupByCols.map(col): _*)
  .agg(jsonField.as("jsonField"))
```

Where the jsonField is

```
 val jsonField=  map(
lit("label_name"),
to_json(
  collect_set(struct(
    col("date").as("Date"),
    col("order_id").as("Order id")))
```

So it is a structure of columns. 
The Spark version is 2.4.3

Comment: What are you using to represent your JSON?

Comment: collect_set(struct(Array(
            col("date").as("Date"),
            col("order_id").as("Order id")) :_*))

Comment: This looks like Spark, is that right?

Comment: Correct. Tagged appropriately.

Comment: Can I help with any other information?

Comment: What does your current input dataframe look like? Can you format the input in the question in datafram/dataset format? If it is an array column, then array of what? Also please specify Spark version.

Comment: Edited the question. If there's anything else please let me know. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @Dawid  do `sortby` on `col("date")` before `collect` and then use `collect_list` instead of `collect_set` to preserve the order.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to combine collect_list with distinctness?

Comment: Looks like adding array_distinct() might be doing the job.